# Service Worker stores files in Content Cache files with content-length: 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, browser-cache

While developing a PWA, I'm using a service worker to download and store files in a cache.
I noticed all text resources (json, js, css, html) all had content-length 0 as they were not being cached.
While all other files (images, sounds, fonts) had valid content lengths.

I'm using Chrome 89.0.4389.114.

Answer (score 0):

The only common point I noticed was the **Accept-Encoding: gzip** so I decided to turn compression off.
And now it is working. All files have a non 0 length.

**Workaround:**

I'm using Spring Boot on the server side, so to turn it off, you need to set a property to false.

```
server.compression.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this ignoreVary option before precacheAndRoute works for me!

```
import { getOrCreatePrecacheController } from 'workbox-precaching/utils/getOrCreatePrecacheController';
getOrCreatePrecacheController().strategy.matchOptions = {
  ignoreVary: true,
};
precacheAndRoute([...])
```